Solving the equation $\sin x-\sin(2x)-\cos(3x)=0$
I need the solution for the equation $\sin x-\sin(2x)-\cos(3x)=0$. It has to be solved using trigonometric identities (not by graph).
I have tried using the identity $\sin x-\sin y=2\sin\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)$ and then applying the half angle identities. I reached the following equation after squaring on both sides
$$1-\cos x+\cos(3x)-\cos x\cos(3x)=\cos^2(3x)$$
After that I tried applying identities to express products as sum and sums as products, but no avail.
I have ended up in a loop. Even tried using the identity $$\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos x$$ but it also did not help.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

What have you tried ? Where exactly are you facing a problem ?

try and use the identity: $\sin(a)-\sin(b)=2\cos(\frac{a+b}{2})\sin(\frac{a-b}{2})$
